# move sharepoint site from central administration to its own collection

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Someone created a site under the Central Administration site collection. I need to move it to its own collection.

I tried using Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb, but I get the this error:

```
Import-SPWeb : Cannot import site. The exported site is based on the template S
TS#0 but the destination site is based on the template STS#1. You can import si
tes only into sites that are based on same template as the exported site.
At line:1 char:13
+ Import-SPWeb <<<<  -Identity http://***** -Path ***************
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletImportWeb:
   SPCmdletImportWeb) [Import-SPWeb], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletImportWe
   b
```

How do I fix this? Or is this even the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

First, which template is STS#0?

```
PS K:\> get-spwebtemplate "sts#0"

Name                 Title                                    LocaleId   Custom
----                 -----                                    --------   ------
STS#0                Team Site                                1033       False
```

Armed with this information, I was able to create a new collection with the correct template and complete the import.